# Have multiple divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, alignment

Essentially, I want to make a "color spectrum" where I have multiple individual colored divs next to each other, each with a link to a different site. So far, I have this:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:500px;background-color:#FF0000"; onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor: pointer;"</div>
```

Google is simply a reference url, I don't have the exact ones yet.

Anyways on to the point.

I've looked at several threads on SO, and have been unsuccessful in finding a way to put 6 of these divs next to each other in order to have a rainbow of colors. Everything I have tried puts them underneath the one before it. I know it will be a lame color spectrum if it only has 6 colors, but that is okay.

Although, if there's a way to blend the divs together as well (while still preserving their "hitbox" to be forwarded to a link) in order to give it a bit more of a "rainbowy" feel, that would be very helpful too. But getting them in order is more important. For now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious ways to achieve this (without scripting). [Live examples here](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgu/bjb51Lzx/)

1. Colored link elements: Use individual colors on each `<a href=""></a>` to get a blocky color spectrum that can be clicked on, leading to different pages.

   - Pros: Easy to code; User sees defined clickable boundaries.
   - Cons: Background isn't very customizable, unless setting different styles for each link, which may not be very smooth (esp. for gradients)
   - Result:

     [image: Method #1]
2. Hidden link elements: Use a background element and overlay `<a href=""></a>` tags, letting you have any background you want.

   - Pros: Customizable background
   - Cons: If using a gradient, compatibility is difficult; You manage your own spacing and the user does not see defined clickable boundaries.
   - Result:

     [image: Method #2]

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left;` or `display:inline-block;` to show them in 1 line, just make sure parent container is not collapsing and is wide enough.

you can use gradients as background colors to blend them together.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

lazy example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJZQzq

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of of each section being a different color. I'm using anchor tags instead of divs because they are links to other sites. This is a better practice than using inline javascript.
http://jsfiddle.net/78x6ub2k/

My html looks like:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="color1" class="color">
</a>
<a href="http://google.com" id="color2" class="color">
</a>
<a href="http://google.com" id="color3" class="color">
</a>
<a href="http://google.com" id="color4" class="color">
</a>
<a href="http://google.com" id="color5" class="color">
</a>
<a href="http://google.com" id="color6" class="color">
</a>
```

and my css looks like:

```
.color {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
}
#color1{
    background: #ff0000;
}
#color2{
    background: #ff9000;
}
#color3{
    background: #faff00;
}
#color4{
    background: #0cff00;
}
#color5{
    background: #0019ff;
}
#color6{
    background: #7700ff;
}
```

Here is an example with the colors faded together. I added a div around the links and gave it a css gradient (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
http://jsfiddle.net/6n4pg254/

My html looks like:

```
<div class="colors">
    <a href="http://google.com" id="color1" class="color">
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com" id="color2" class="color">
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com" id="color3" class="color">
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com" id="color4" class="color">
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com" id="color5" class="color">
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com" id="color6" class="color">
    </a>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like:

```
.color {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.colors {
    width:632px;
    background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 14%, #d87b29 17%, #d87b29 31%, #ede62d 34%, #ede62d 48%, #2ae030 52%, #2ae030 65%, #2e48f4 68%, #2e48f4 83%, #921c96 86%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(14%,#ff3232), color-stop(17%,#d87b29), color-stop(31%,#d87b29), color-stop(34%,#ede62d), color-stop(48%,#ede62d), color-stop(52%,#2ae030), color-stop(65%,#2ae030), color-stop(68%,#2e48f4), color-stop(83%,#2e48f4), color-stop(86%,#921c96)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 14%,#d87b29 17%,#d87b29 31%,#ede62d 34%,#ede62d 48%,#2ae030 52%,#2ae030 65%,#2e48f4 68%,#2e48f4 83%,#921c96 86%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 14%,#d87b29 17%,#d87b29 31%,#ede62d 34%,#ede62d 48%,#2ae030 52%,#2ae030 65%,#2e48f4 68%,#2e48f4 83%,#921c96 86%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 14%,#d87b29 17%,#d87b29 31%,#ede62d 34%,#ede62d 48%,#2ae030 52%,#2ae030 65%,#2e48f4 68%,#2e48f4 83%,#921c96 86%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 14%,#d87b29 17%,#d87b29 31%,#ede62d 34%,#ede62d 48%,#2ae030 52%,#2ae030 65%,#2e48f4 68%,#2e48f4 83%,#921c96 86%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#921c96',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

In either case, I am using the property "display:inline-block" to make an element appear inline will retaining sizing and other block-like characteristics. You could also use "display:block" and "float:left" to make all the items float to the left. Though this can result in some odd behavior if you are not familiar with how floats work.

Comment: So I tried out your second version, with them blended together, and it looks awesome! Only things are I can't get it to display on a Weebly site. I tried pasting the CSS into the website CSS at the bottom under it's own section, but when I put the html into the "embed code" tool, it just shows up blank. I don't know if you're familiar with Weebly, but is there a way I can put the CSS into the html code itself, and have everything as one code?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I jsut realized I forgot to close off the header so it thought the whole CSS was a header. Heh heh... Just one more thing. Can you make the gradients a little more drastic? I just want it to look like it flows just a little better.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments. Is there also an easy way to add mouseover text to each color? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/71gun45r/ . You can add a span inside the link, then use the :hover pseudo selector to change the opacity of the span on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Simplified my answer after looking at what @pankijs posted - thanks!

You can use gradient backgronds, please have a look at this example (I'm using just 4 blocks but you can get the idea):

http://jsfiddle.net/r3bk65ys/3/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div><a href="#" class="rainbow one"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="rainbow two"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="rainbow three"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="rainbow four"></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main div {
    float: left;
}

.main .rainbow {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}

.one {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, orange);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, orange); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, orange); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , orange); 
}
.two {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange, yellow);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, yellow); 
}
.three {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, yellow, green);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, yellow, green); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, yellow, green); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green); 
}
.four {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green, blue);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, green, blue); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, green, blue); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green, blue); 
}
```

But by all means there are multiple ways of achieving the same results and some might fit your environment / JavaScript library of choice better - adding more details to your question might help.

References:

- [Gradient background](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)
- [CSS3 Gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `display:inline-block` to have the divs on the same line.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:500px;background-color:#FF0000;display:inline-block"; onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor: pointer;"</div>
```

You might have to adjust the width so the divs fit on one line.
You can use `%` widths for best fit.

**In a 7-colour rainbow:** 100 / 7 = ~14.3.  So just set each div to `width:14.3%`